# sales_order_place_before Changing Customer Group not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have a customerGroupCheck function, which is loaded successfull and every data in this functions is correct.

In some case I want to change the user group, but it won't save. Do you have any idea?

```
$observer = $getObserver['order'];
$getShippingAddress = $observer->getShippingAddress()->getData();
$customerGroupId = $observer->getCustomerGroupId();
$customerId = $observer->getCustomerId();           

        switch($getShippingAddress['country_id']) {
            case 'DE':
                echo 'country_id: DE';
                $observer->setData('customer_group_id', 6);
            default:
                echo 'country_id: else';
                $observer->setData('customer_group_id', 11);
        }
```

I want to change the group by submitting the order.
This is the XML Part

```
        <sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                <namespace>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Sales_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customerGroupCheck</method>
                </namespace>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
```

This is my code now:

```
public function customerGroupCheck($getObserver) {      
    $order = $getObserver['order'];
    $getShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
    $customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
    $customer = $order->getCustomer();

    switch($getShippingAddress['country_id']) {
        case 'DE':
            if($customerGroupId == 4 || $customerGroupId == 6 || $customerGroupId == 11) { // B2B
                $customer->setData('group_id', 6)->save();
            }
            if($customerGroupId == 9 || $customerGroupId == 10 || $customerGroupId == 12) { // B2C
                $customer->setData('group_id', 9)->save();
            }
            break;
```

But it won't work at all. Do I miss something or made a bad mistake?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you clarified your question. What event are you listening to, are you submitting an order, creating a quote, etc.?

Comment: If create an order on frontend checkout

Comment: OK, looking at `customerGroupCheck`, your customer accounts are updated. Correct? However, your order and quote are not updated with the desired customer group ID. Is this also correct?

Comment: The account isn't updated, if i send the order. Thats the problem and i don't know why

Comment: Are you sure your observer is working? `$customer->setData(...)->save()` should save the customer. It will thrown an error if it doesn't save.

Comment: There is no error or something else. can you maybe contact me at cb@design-busse.de ?

Comment: I also tryed
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
        $sql = "update `customer_entity` set `group_id` = 4 where`entity_id` =".$customerId;
        $write->query($sql);
But it wount work at all.

Comment: @Chris, do you solved it? I have the exact same problem in Magento 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't too clear as to what you're actually trying to do. So, I'm going to assume you're submitting an order and want to change the customer's group as the customer checks out. `$observer` seems to be actually an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` (you should probably change that variable name to `$order`). Correct me if I'm wrong.

The reason customer group ID isn't changing is that you're setting data on the order object. You will need to load the customer object and save it, if you want to have the group ID change take effect. Like below..

```
$customer = $order->getCustomer();
$customer->setData('group_id', $id)->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use another event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

This is fired if a quote(cart) is converted to a order.

```
$order->getCustomer()->setData('group_id', $newGroupId);
```

Do not invoke `save()`, because it **will be** invoked right after the event.

Comment: i removed "save" and also changed the event to sales_model_service_quote_submit_before, bit it doen't work at all

Comment: After reading your feedback on other questions, I think you've some other problems with your data/settings... What happens when you update it manually from the backend? What happens when you change the data in the database directly. Maybe some other module screws up, try disabling them, going into developermode and try again

Comment: If i run the sql directly or change it in the backend, its working fine.

Comment: You could test by going to the file `Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php` check the `_beforeSave` `_afterSave` and echo the `object->getData()` and try tracing back from there